# Why did Community suddenly delete posts in bulk about an hour ago?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, community-user

I just opened up Stack Overflow, and realized I had a -4 in my reputation. I thought I'd been downvoted, and clicked on the two posts that showed the -4. Turns out, I hadn't even answered these posts, but edited them back in '12 when I didn't have edit privileges. Both of these posts had been deleted by Community an hour ago.

I went into the 10k tools and found a fair amount of posts deleted by Community (both with and without answers. Granted, none of the deleted questions were all that good, but I would like to know why they were specifically deleted now? Is there some sort of cleanup script that runs every now and then, or something else?

Here's a list of the questions I could find:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/11265480/1069068
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/11285569/1069068
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/1211819/1069068
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/1115040/1069068
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/1067391/1069068
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/2307633/1069068
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/2696585/1069068
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/2703313/1069068
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/3209103/1069068
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/3332762/1069068
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/3383578/1069068
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/3419313/1069068
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/3784350/1069068
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/3682889/1069068
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/3462565/1069068
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/3967093/1069068

Comment: They should be covered off by [Enable automatic deletion of old, unanswered zero-score questions after a year?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year)

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards But some of the questions had upvoted answers. The Question you linked to states that the answers shouldn't be with a score > 0

Comment: Sorry @Raghav, I must have missed those. I thought I looked through them all...

Comment: The upvoted answer are deleted by a mod, then the question itself has no answer and fulfill the condition for auto clean up.

Comment: All the ones with upvoted answers had the answers deleted...

Comment: Ah yes. I see. I missed the answers getting deleted.

Comment: I think Shog's answer to the "Turbocharging the Roomba" question has the most up-to-date protocol for this.

Comment: @BradLarson Shog edited Jeff's answer on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year to be accurate and up to date.